# Using gsub function to replace words by reading a .csv file

Tags: r, replace, gsub

```
setwd("C:\\Users\\Joshua\\Documents\\TextMining\\Description_text")
library(RTextTools)
library(topicmodels)
library(tm)
library(SnowballC)

#Seizure
#cnamePS=file.path("C:\\Users\\Joshua\\Documents\\TextMining\\")
cnamePS=file.path("C:\\Users\\Joshua\\Documents\\TextMining\\Description_text")
docs <- Corpus(DirSource(cnamePS), readerControl=list(reader=readPlain))

#clean file
docsA <- tm_map(docs, removePunctuation)
docsA <- tm_map(docsA, removeNumbers)

docsA=tm_map(docsA,content_transformer(tolower))
docsA=tm_map(docsA,removeWords,stopwords("english"))

#phrase replacement
phrasesReplacement <- read.csv("C:\\Users\\Joshua\\Documents\\TextMining\\phrases.csv", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
replacePhrasesFunc <- function(txt, replacementtable)
{

  txt<-gsub("-","",txt)

  for (r in seq(nrow(replacementtable)))
  {
    txt <- gsub(replacementtable$phrase[r], replacementtable$replacement[r], txt, fixed=TRUE)
  }
  return(txt)
}

replacePhrases <- content_transformer(replacePhrasesFunc)

docsA <- tm_map(docsA, replacePhrases, phrasesReplacement)#keep phrase


#docsAcopy=docsA #make copy

#docsA=tm_map(docsA,stemDocument) 

docsA=tm_map(docsA,stripWhitespace)
```

Hi, I am trying to do some Textmining for some research, however I keep getting one error in one part of my code.

```
> docsA <- tm_map(docsA, replacePhrases, phrasesReplacement)#keep phrase
Error in gsub(replacementtable$phrase[r], replacementtable$replacement[r],  : 
  invalid 'pattern' argument
Called from: gsub(replacementtable$phrase[r], replacementtable$replacement[r], 
    txt, fixed = TRUE)
```

Unfortunately as I am new to R, I cannot seem to figure why the error keeps reoccurring. Thanks for any help if possible.

[So the .csv file I use is formatted as such..](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KKNpz.png)

[So here is the debugging information.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oFtMT.png)

Comment: Try `options(error=recover)` before you run this code. That will launch the debugger when you get the error, and you can see what `replacementtable$phrase[r]` looks like.

Comment: I think there might be some reserved metacharacters present in your data which is leading to this, for example , presence of "(" or "+" or "*" etc have special meaning, if your data contain these symbols, then this errors happen, unless these are escaped with "\\".

Comment: Thanks for looking at it. I have launched the debugger and posted what I saw. 
What does "\\" do sorry.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out that it was a problem with my .csv file.

I was missing a comma in between words.

A good reminder that the smallest things can cause the whole code to not work.